# Keep track of chained Queueable

Tags: asynchronous, queueable-interface

I'd like to insert a lot of records. Chaining `Queueable` classes seems to be the way to go in my scenario, I am just wondering if the following is feasible:

- **keep track of chained jobs** - when first job is fired, I get the job's Id, but how should I know that the 'nested' job has finished? Perhaps it's better to fire jobs in loop, than nesting them?
- **limits** - is each `queueable` fired in separate transaction, or there is common limit for all of them (in loop, or chained)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> keep track of chained jobs

Unless you save those job IDs somewhere, there's really no way to tell when a chain of Queueable jobs are done. There's no mechanism we have access to that allows us to identify jobs spawned from other jobs. It could be as simple as a custom setting that you poll every few seconds, or it could be more complicated, like counting the number of records already created. If you really want many transactions linked together, you might consider Batchable instead: all of the execute methods are separate transactions, but linked to a master job ID. When the single job is done, you'd know all the records were created.

> limits

Each execute method is its own transaction, so that means they each get their own governor limits (60 seconds CPU, 12 MB heap, 50k query rows, and so on). If you queue them in a loop, you can place 50 Queueables into the queue in a single synchronous transaction. When you chain, there's a limit of 1 Queueable per execute method, so they cannot have "rabbit population" resource usage explosions, and in Sandboxes and Developer orgs, have an additional limit of 5 chains, which can be more challenging to test properly. Also, using Queueable in a loop has a decaying execution time. In other words, each additional Queueable beyond the first will be scheduled further out in time. A Batchable class doesn't suffer from that limitation, although you're more limited in how many Batchables you can have in the queue at once.

---

Most likely, you'll want to try Batchable instead of Queueable. Queueable is generally preferred over future methods, when you can help it, because it gives you a job ID, and so allows you to monitor a job, unlike future methods, which are "fire and forget" type jobs. However, Batchable is still generally preferred over Queueable when you simply have a ton of records you need to process asynchronously, because they're a little more resilient to governor limits, and allow you to monitor an entire chain of executions from a single job ID. For example, with chained Queueable, if you hit a single execution limit, the chain is broken and you're done. With Batchable, you can determine how many executes failed, and the entire chain can still be processed even in the event of governor limit exceptions.